# app-root is empty in asp.net after publishing in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have embedded angular 5 app with ASP.NET MVC, 
I am calling the dist files in bundleConfig.cs like this :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bundles")
               .Include(
               "~/ngTDS/dist/inline.*",
               "~/ngTDS/dist/styles.*",
               "~/ngTDS/dist/polyfills.*",
               "~/ngTDS/dist/scripts.*",
               "~/ngTDS/dist/vendor.*",
               "~/ngTDS/dist/main.*"));
```

But after publishing the app in IIS, I can't see the angular UI inside the `<app-root></app-root>` which I referred in index.cshtml.

Angular is  not working, What can I do ?

Comment: Check your browser console, any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code in .csproj file

```
<Target Name="Build Angular" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" BeforeTargets="Build">    
   <Message Text="* * * * * * Building Angular App * * * * * *" Importance="high" />
   <Exec Command="ng build -prod -aot" />
</Target>
```

It is working https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa